# Can google host my kml file (all my site)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

i want to save all user's (who visite my site) map ,

but  i think google can hosting those kml file , yes ??

http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_javascript.html

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the Google Maps Data API to save and retrieve map data. The API also serves as a way to programmatically access Google My Maps.